# In vert.x is there a way of forwarding the replyAddress() to another service so it responds to the original request?

Tags: vert.x

I have:

- REST frontend
- Service A
- Service B
- Service C

the flow is:
User -http-> REST -> -eventBus-> A -eventBus-> B -eventBus-> C -eventBus-> REST -http-> User

I'd like to use something like eventBus.request(...) but I need the service C to do the msg.reply(...).

I tried passing the replyAddress() from A to B to C and just sending back the response to the using eventBus.send(replyAddress, ...), but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running Vert.x in clustered mode? You can't use the reply address directly in clustered mode.

Comment: Totally - that's what I am observing. In clustered mode sending to the replyAddress doesn't seem to work. I did some debugging and the ClusteredMessage has also a senderId. I am guessing this is used also to correlate the response but the senderId is not exposed, so there is no way to copy it from the original message... My current approach is to do User -> REST.request -> A.request -> B.request -> C.reply -> B.reply -> A.reply -> REST -> User. But it requires all the A, B to be alive when C finishes which can be a lot to ask in a distributed system...

Answer (score 0):

> My current approach is to do `User -> REST.request -> A.request -> B.request -> C.reply -> B.reply -> A.reply -> REST -> User`. But it requires all the A, B to be alive when C finishes which can be a lot to ask in a distributed system...

Let `REST` register an EventBus handler under a certain address which is known to `C`, so `C` can send the reply to that address.

You could, for example, name that address `reply_address` to give it a more generic meaning. Then you could build a reply-mechanism around that, which you could reuse in other services of your application which need to reply across boundaries.